# Form onSubmit with Javascript not Working Correctly in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

OK, I submitted a question a little while ago pertaining to an animated loading GIF not displaying while an image is uploading ( PHP ).  Now, I've managed to get the GIF to display while an image is uploading, but in IE and Firefox the loading GIF never goes away ( and / because ? ) the form never submits.  In Chrome, the GIF goes away and the form submits.  The following is what I have doing it..

```
<!-- Validates form -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script>
function validationloading(){
    // post box blank
    var x=document.forms["livefeed"]["message"].value;
    if (!$.trim($("#styled").val())){
        document.livefeed.message.focus();
        document.livefeed.message.style.border="solid 1px red";
        alert("Cannot post a blank message.");
        return false;
    }

    document.write("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' align='center' width='100%' height='130'><tr><td align='center' valign='center'><img src='images/ajax_loader.gif' width='50' height='50'></td></tr></table>");
    return true
    $("#myform").submit();
}
</script>
```

The following snip is what calls it from the form..

```
onSubmit="javascript: validationloading()"
```

I've tried shuffling the return true value around and it changes the results but not in the way I need.  It'll submit in IE and Firefox but not display the loading GIF.  I know my code is a pile of slop, but that's why I'm here.

**The following works 100% across the three browsers..  I appreciate all your help, guys !**

```
<!-- validates form and displays loading gif -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script>
function validationloading(){
    // post box blank
    var x=document.forms["livefeed"]["message"].value;
    if (!$.trim($("#styled").val())){
        document.livefeed.message.focus();
        document.livefeed.message.style.border="solid 1px red";
        alert("Cannot post a blank message.");
        return false;
    }
    //

    document.livefeed.submit(); 
    document.getElementById("gif_block").style.display="block"; //gif_block is the id of the div outside the image
    document.getElementById('livefeed').style.display ='none';
    return true;

}
</script>
```

**and the GIF div is this..**

```
<div id="gif_block" style="display:none" align="center" ><p><image src="images/ajax_loader.gif" id="loader-img" width="50" height-"50" /></p></div>
```

Comment: OK, I wish I could accept both..  I accepted an answer.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- `javascript:` is only meaningful in `href` or `action` attributes - basically wherever you might find a URL. It is a scheme to indicate JavaScript code to be run. In an event handler or a `<script>` tag, it's just a label that you might use as part of a loop.
- `return` always ends execution of the current block, so it makes absolutely no sense to `return true` and then try to `$("#myform").submit();`.
- In fact, that `$("#myform").submit()` is potentially dangerous in that it may well cause an infinite loop: by submitting the form within its own `onSubmit` handler, you fire the handler again and try to submit the form anew, and so on.
- `document.write()` will overwrite the entire page if it's not being called while the page is loading. While in this case that's not really too much of an issue, I'm fairly sure it's not what you were intending to do.
- `document.forms` is obsolete, you should instead use proper DOM methods like `getElementById`. However in this case you could just pass `this` as an argument to `validationloading` and it will refer to the form being submitted. I'm assuming this is similar to why you have `document.livefeed.message` - use `getElementById` for these.
- You never actually do anything with the return value of the function. You need to `return` it up the stack: `onSubmit="return validationloading();"`

The number one issue is the `document.write` thing. Remove that and the `.submit()` after it, and everything will be fine. There's no need to add a "loading" GIF unless you're using AJAX.

Comment: I really appreciate the info you posted, but you're telling me there's no need to add a loading GIF..  ?  I've adjusted my PHP.ini to accept larger image files ( I wrote PHP code to resize and compress them.. ).  When someone uploads a large image, it can take up to 30 seconds.  I just wanted an animated loading GIF to display while the image is uploading, so they don't start refreshing the page, etc..

Comment: *"by submitting the form within its own `onSubmit` handler, you fire the handler again and try to submit the form anew, and so on."* Programmatically submitting a form doesn't trigger the `onsubmit` handler.

Comment: @user1799250: No, he/she is telling you that `document.write` is not the right way to add it.

Comment: Right, I get it now..  Ok, I appreciate all your help, guys..  I'll have to use a more appropriate piece of code to display the GIF..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. If you want `validationloading` to prevent the submission via its return value, you need to add `return` to that:

   ```
   onsubmit="return validationloading()"
   ```

   That's because under-the-covers, the browser converts the above to a handler function that looks something like this:

   ```
   function(event) {
       // ...your code here...
   }
   ```

   ...and uses the return value of *that* function.
2. If you use `document.write` in a loaded page, the entire page content is wiped out and *replaced* with what you output in `document.write`. I wouldn't be surprised if that interfered with the form submission. `document.write` has basically no place in web apps and hasn't for the last 12 years or so. :-) Use the DOM objects and methods to add elements to the page, and/or to change their styling so you hide some and reveal others. (A bit of searching on your favorite search engine should give you plenty to work with.)
3. You have code that can never be reached: The `submit` call after the `return true`.

   ```
   return true
   $("#myform").submit(); // <== This code will never run
   ```

   `return` exits the function, so the code after it will never run.

Other notes (which are almost certainly *not* the problem):

- With `onxyz` handler attributes, you don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol. Their content is *already* JavaScript. You only use `javascript:` where a URL is expected, as with the `href` on a link. It doesn't cause an error, though, usually, because it looks like a [labelled statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12) to the JavaScript engine.
- The proper attribute name is in all lower case. It only matters if you're doing XHTML, though, so it probably doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Yea, thanks, I just made that edit for the sake of being syntactically correct.  The IE and Firefox issue remains though - the GIF sticks and the form doesn't sumbmit.

Comment: I just tried taking the AJAX submit part out and it doesn't seem to matter if it's there or not.  The code executes the exact same way.  I don't think it's doing anything.  YOu're right.

Comment: @user1799250: As Teemu indicated, the `document.write` is very likely to be a problem.